# VueJS - Emit event to several components (with varying parents)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a bunch of Vue Components like this:

```
App.js
 |
 |-- CreateTasks
 |
 |-- LatestTasks (lists 20 tasks)
 |
 |-- FooBar
 |   |---LatestTasks (lists 10 tasks)
```

When making a task in the `CreateTasks` I would like to emit an event, that is caught in any other LatestTasks-component, so it knows to update the list.

I can't get this to work, though.

Here is my code:

**In CreateTasks**

```
  methods: {
    createTask(){
      let task = { name: 'newTask' };
      this.$emit( 'new-task-created' );
    }
  }
```

**In LatestTasks**

```
  methods: {
    getLatestTasks(){
      ...
    }
  }
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('new-task-created', this.getLatestTasks );
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

You are better off using Vuex or redux.  But if you just want to use events, or it's a quick small app where you just need a quick hack:

Attach events to the root element:

```
this.$root.$on('myevent',function(data){console.log(data)})
```

Then emit the events from the root element:

```
this.$root.$emit('myevent',{data:1234}}
```

---

Or create an EventBus:

```
// eventbus.js
import Vue from 'vue'
const EventBus = new Vue()
export default EventBus
```

Listen on EventBus:

```
// component1.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import EventBus from './eventbus'
Vue.component('component1', {
  mounted () {
    EventBus.$on('myevent', function (data) {
       console.log(data)
    });
  }
});
```

Emit event on EventBus:

```
// component2.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import EventBus from './eventbus'
Vue.component('component2', {
  methods: {
    emitMethod () {
       EventBus.$emit('myevent', {data: 1234});
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose it's most suitable to use `Vuex`. Instead of emitting an event in `createTask()`, you can `dispatch()` an action to the Vuex store. And in every component which you want to be aware of this data you add a computed property which links to specific Vuex getter.

[Vuex Docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)

Another option would be to emit an event as you initially proposed, but you'll have to listen for it in the parent component and then to store it in a local variable in that parent component and finally create a `prop` for each component which will receive the updated newTask.

I hope this helps, if you wish I can give you more detailed example for implementation.